# Spark - Reducing number of combinations using a groupBy

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

Let's say I have a dataset in the following form:

```
data = sc.parallelize([('customer_1', 'contract_1', 15000, 100), 
                       ('customer_1', 'contract_1', 20000, 200),
                       ('customer_2', 'contract_2', 30000, 100), 
                       ('customer_1', 'contract_1', 7500, 500)], 2)
```

In which:

- First column represents a customer id.
- Second column represents a contract id.
- Third column represents a timestamp.
- Fourth column is contract value.

What I need to do is to add an extra column that, for each row, contains the sum of contract value for all the rows with same customer id, same contract id and with timestamp equal or greater than the timestamp of the current row.

So, for the previous dataset, result should be:

```
customer_1 contract_1 15000 300  # 300 = 100+200
customer_1 contract_1 20000 200  # 200
customer_2 contract_2 30000 100  # 100
customer_1 contract_1  7500 800  # 800 = 100+200+500
```

If timestamp check wouldn't be there, it could be done setting a key composed by customer id and contract id, reducing by key and then a join but given timestamp comparison is there, I don't find an easy way of doing this.

My first approach for getting this done is using a cartesian operation in this way:

```
combinations = data.cartesian(data)
               .filter(lambda a: a[0][0] == a[1][0] and  
                                 a[0][1] == a[1][1] and 
                                 a[1][2] >= a[0][2])
agg = combinations.map(lambda a: (a[0], a[1][3])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

The result is ok but I am afraid applying a cartesian to the amount of data I am managing (more than 1 million of rows) is quite inefficient. In fact applying a cartesian operation here is producing a lot of combinations that don't make sense at all (by definition doesn't make sense combining rows of different customers or contracts) that are later removed by the filter.

The ideal case for me would be doing a `groupBy` using customer id and contract id as the key and then, iterate through the resulting `groupBy`, and apply a cartesian product to each row. This would highly reduce the number of combinations generated. However, I didn't find any way to do this. Even more, is this possible? if so, How? Do you have any other recommendation/idea about how to achieve my requirement?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that asks for a window function:

```py
import sys
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

df = data.toDF(["customer_id", "contract_id", "timestamp", "value"])
w = (Window()
    .partitionBy("customer_id", "contract_id")
    .orderBy("timestamp")
    # Current row and future values
    .rangeBetween(0, sys.maxsize)) # or .rowsBetween(0, sys.maxsize)

result = df.withColumn("future_value", sum("value").over(w))
result.show()

## +-----------+-----------+---------+-----+------------+
## |customer_id|contract_id|timestamp|value|future_value|
## +-----------+-----------+---------+-----+------------+
## | customer_1| contract_1|     7500|  500|         800|
## | customer_1| contract_1|    15000|  100|         300|
## | customer_1| contract_1|    20000|  200|         200|
## | customer_2| contract_2|    30000|  100|         100|
## +-----------+-----------+---------+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much zero323. I am right beginning with Spark and didn't know about Window functions. Thanks for the information. Just one more question out of curiosity: what if I have a timestamp_start and timestamp_end fields and my the condition for summing up is having current_row_timestamp_start >= timestamp_start and current_row_timestamp_end <= timestamp_end? Could I use Window functions also for this case? Thanks!

Comment: No. You can provide a static range covering either rows or values but it cannot depend on a current row. Theoretically you can look backwards and forwards with lag / lead and try to build something from that but it is unlikely to be pretty or efficient.